Join three tables and filter by date
We have the following three tables:
Table: "Movie"

id = ID of movie
title: name of the movie

Table "Actor"

id = ID of Actor
title: name of the Actor

Table: "Statistics" (where the stats are located)

movie_id: ID of the movie
actor_id: ID of the actor
year: Year
month: Month
day: Day
total_pc: number of Positive Critics
total_nc: number of negative critics
total_revenue: total revenue

I need to create a report with the following fields:

Month
Day
Name of Movie
Name of Actor
Total Positive Critics
Total Negative Critics
Total Revenue

The query must only extract data from Movies with the letter “S” in their titles, and only
from August 28th 2013 to September 5th 2014.
I've came up with
UPDATE setlists
SET full_date = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day), '%Y-%m-%d');

SELECT S.month AS Month, S.day AS Day, M.title AS Name_of_Movie,  A.title AS Name_of_Actor, S.total_pc  AS Total_Positive_Critics, S.total_nc AS Total_Negative_Critics, S.total_revenue AS Total_Revenue
FROM Statistics S
JOIN Movie M ON M.id = S.movie_id
JOIN Actor A ON A.id = S.app_id
WHERE S.full_date BETWEEN '2013-08-28' AND '2014-09-05' AND C.title LIKE '%S%'

Am I on the right path here, or is there a right or better way to do it

Calling it a theoretical question doesn't make sense, you want a SQL answer... and you could (and should) mock up some data for us using DBFiddle. So please provide a [MRE] with sample raw data, and desired results.

For starters, you join tables BEFORE your where statement. Next, read a bit more on LIKE.

Why use a scalar UDF and not DATEFROMPARTS? Are you on SQL Server 2005?

@Thom A, I couldn't understand how to use DATEFROMPARTS to select between a date range,

Exactly the same way as your scalar UDF, it's why it makes no sense that you created one; a function with the exact same functionality exists.

With your latest changes, you are almost there. The LIKE '%s' will select movie titles that end in "s". You need to tweak that to get titles that contain "s". Regarding DATEFROMPARTS, that is related to the date_ymd column that you are referencing, but is not included in your posted table schema. If that column exists, great - no action needed. If not, the DATEFROMPARTS function can be used to construct a combined date from separate year/month/day components.

... Other than that, my only suggestion is cosmetic: when lines start to get too long it is good practice to add line breaks and/or indentation for readability. Your future colleagues will thank you.  Good luck in your studies and future career.

Storing day, month and year in three separate columns is stupid. Put them all in one date column, then you can use normal date comparisons. LEFT JOIN doesn't make sense here because how could you have a stat without a movie, or a movie without an actor? You probably want [INNER] JOIN instead.

@Charlieface I just updated the table getting a column with a full date, and then filtering by it. I guess that's fine now, and more straightforward no?

@FernandoAnalytics - Your post is tagged as SQL Server, but your latest update is using the STR_TO_DATE() function that appears to be a MySql function. If you are in gfact using MySql, please update the tags in your post. These are two different products. (This might also explain the earlier DATEFROMPARTS () confusion, since that is a SQL Server function.)

@TN, changed. I'm using mysql, sorry. What do you think about the changes in the code?
